# How do I run a program with a different working directory from current, from Linux shell?

Tags: linux, shell, environment

Using a **Linux shell**, how do I start a program with a different working directory from the current working directory?

For example, I have a binary file `helloworld` that creates the file `hello-world.txt` in the **current directory**. 

This file is inside of directory `/a`.

Currently, I am in the directory `/b`. I want to start my program running `../a/helloworld` and get the `hello-world.txt` somewhere in a third directory `/c`.

Comment: I discovered the hard way that `su` resets the working directory to the home directory of user you specify before running any `-c` commands. This was very helpful to me.

Comment: It's been 12 years since I've posted this question and today I looked it up myself, cause I could not recall how to do that.

Comment: It's one thing to come back to a SO post with `a:visited` link and an upvote already on it. It's another thing when you're the asker, or even the answerer. There should be a badge for that... "Forgetful"

Answer (score 675, accepted):

Call the program like this:

```
(cd /c; /a/helloworld)
```

The parentheses cause a sub-shell to be spawned. This sub-shell then changes its working directory to `/c`, then executes `helloworld` from `/a`. After the program exits, the sub-shell terminates, returning you to your prompt of the parent shell, in the directory you started from.

**Error handling:** To avoid running the program without having changed the directory, e.g. when having misspelled `/c`, make the execution of `helloworld` conditional:

```
(cd /c && /a/helloworld)
```

**Reducing memory usage:** To avoid having the subshell waste memory while hello world executes, call `helloworld` via exec:

```
(cd /c && exec /a/helloworld)
```

[Thanks to [Josh and Juliano](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/786376/how-do-i-run-a-program-with-a-different-working-directory-from-current-from-linu/786515#786515) for giving tips on improving this answer!]

Comment: Any way to pass arguments to this shell? As in $1, and $2?

Comment: @segfault: The subshell has complete access to the surrounding scope.

Comment: Seems like it is temporarily in that directory anyway, isn't it?

Comment: You can pass all arguments by doing $*, $@ or "$@" (if you want arguments to respect double quotes)

Comment: WIll it work if I add this line to /etc/rc.d/rc.local ?

Comment: This is brilliant answer; how can I check if process executed via `()` finished successfully?

Comment: the entire `()` construct will have the exitcode of the last command inside. You can check that either directly through chaining or by inspecting `$?`.

Answer (score 119):

Similar to [David Schmitt](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/786376/how-to-start-a-programm-with-working-directory-different-from-current-from-linux/786419#786419)'s answer, plus Josh's suggestion, but doesn't leave a shell process running:

```
(cd /c && exec /a/helloworld)
```

This way is more similar to how you usually run commands on the shell. To see the practical difference, you have to run `ps ef` from another shell with each solution.

Comment: [Bash manual builtins **exec**](https://www.gnu.org/software/bash/manual/html_node/Bourne-Shell-Builtins.html#Bourne-Shell-Builtins)

Comment: Just say it here — `exec` _replaces_ the shell process with the given command, without creating a new process.

Answer (score 38):

An option which doesn't require a subshell and is built in to bash

```
(pushd SOME_PATH && run_stuff; popd)
```

Demo:

```
$ pwd
/home/abhijit
$ pushd /tmp # directory changed
$ pwd
/tmp
$ popd
$ pwd
/home/abhijit
```

Comment: A similar suggestion has been done below by Sahil. It does not work if the command fails. Consider `pushd SOME_PATH && run_stuff && popd` -- if run_stuff fails, than popd is not going to be executed.

Comment: Late reply, that depends on the settings of the bash file.  Bash can continue executing commands even after a failed command (unlike using &&), but it can be set to not do that using ``set -e`` in the file and then it would fail to ``popd``.

Comment: Still, I think `pushd "${SOME_PATH}" && run_stuff; popd` is better than the current answer, since the pushd/popd semantics were specifically designed for this situation of going into some directory and then coming back to the original one.

Comment: How does it work as defined as alias and I need to pass a param?

Comment: I think you'd need to write a shell script to which you would pass the parameter that would execute the series of commands as you can't pass a parameter in the middle of an alias.  If you need help writing that, you should ask a separate question and reference this one.  Once you have the shell script, you could write an alias to call your new script.

Comment: Actually, you could use a bash function rather than a shell script, but you still can't use an alias.

Comment: How is it different from a regular `cd` ? Is it more protable ?
Edit: Fount an answer here : https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/272965/pushd-popd-vs-cd-cd-in-bash-and-zsh

Comment: But ... the parentheses create a subshell.

Answer (score 22):

```
sh -c 'cd /c && ../a/helloworld'
```

Comment: Used this for FreeBSD's jexec to execute a command inside jail in specified working directory.

Answer (score 15):

Just change the last "&&" into ";" and it will cd back no matter if the command fails or succeeds:

```
cd SOME_PATH && run_some_command ; cd -
```

Answer (score 9):

I always think UNIX tools should be written as filters, read input from stdin and write output to stdout.  If possible you could change your helloworld binary to write the contents of the text file to stdout rather than a specific file.  That way you can use the shell to write your file anywhere.

```
$ cd ~/b

$ ~/a/helloworld > ~/c/helloworld.txt
```

Comment: +1 for being right, although the answer is only peripherally an answer.

Answer (score 6):

why not keep it simple

`cd SOME_PATH && run_some_command && cd -`

the last 'cd' command will take you back to the last pwd directory. This should work on all *nix systems.

Comment: You are write @mezhaka, should have considered that :)

Comment: Warning: If `run_some_command` fails, `cd -` won't get executed.

Answer (score 4):

One way to do that is to create a wrapper shell script.

The shell script would change the current directory to /c, then run /a/helloworld. Once the shell script exits, the current directory reverts back to /b.

Here's a bash shell script example:

```
#!/bin/bash
cd /c
/a/helloworld
```

Answer (score 2):

If you always want it to go to /C, use an absolute path when you write the file.

Answer (score 2):

The following worked for my simple need to set up an alias to which I can append an argument, without having to put the instructions in a function; worked in Bash and ZSH:

```
$ CWD=/your/target/dir command args
```

My use case: I have a shell script named `run-service` that resolves paths to other files based on its own location. If I call it with `cd ~/Code/company/scripts && run-service dev/some-service`, it will expect to find a config file in `~/Code/company/services/dev/some-service`. So instead of always having to `cd` into the directory and calling the script, I just did this:

```
# Alias definition
alias run-service="CWD=/your/target/dir run-service"

# Calling the alias
$ run-service foo
```

It's probably too simplistic to be of general use, but it works for my basic use-case.

Answer (score -1):

If you want to perform this inside your program then I would do something like:

```
#include <unistd.h>
int main()
{
  if(chdir("/c") < 0 )  
  {
     printf("Failed\n");
     return -1 ;
  }

  // rest of your program...

}
```

Comment: He wants to do that in a shell-script, and not in a C. Also, it would be a horrible idea to subprocess the binary file.