# `sbt run` from outside the project directory

Tags: scala, sbt

When I want to run my Scala project, I `cd` to the project directory and do

```
$ sbt "run arg1"
```

How can I do the same operation from outside the project directory?

Answer (score 28, accepted):

My answer is inpired by this more general question: [How do I run a program with a different working directory from current, from Linux shell?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/786376/how-do-i-run-a-program-with-a-different-working-directory-from-current-from-lin)

```
(cd myPath/; sbt "run arg1")
```

or

```
(cd myPath/ && exec sbt "run arg1")
```

Comment: Thanks.  This works.  The one downside I'm seeing is that it puts a `target` directory in the working directory instead of using the `target` directory that is already in the project directory.  Is there a way to stop it from doing that?

Comment: Generally it works! Remember to remove double quote of sbt command.

Comment: If you want to go back to your original directory, just append `cd -`. example `cd myPath; sbt "run arg1"; cd -`