# How do I change the path of where my program is run from?

Tags: ubuntu-12.04, execution, lazarus

I have built a program on Ubuntu 12.04 using Lazarus.

My development code is in /home/Laz but my binary is put in /urs/local/bin

However, my program shortcut is on the Desktop.

What I need to do:
When the program shortcut is clicked, it all works BUT I want the program to run from within the /usr/local/bin path and NOT from the Desktop where the shortcut is located.

How is this done?

Thanks!

Comment: Have you tried this? http://stackoverflow.com/questions/786376/how-do-i-run-a-program-with-a-different-working-directory-from-current-from-lin

Comment: @r3mus Thank you for your input. I got it working. However, each time I click it, it asks if I want to run or view the contents. Can't we run it without asking any question? Please post an answer so that I may select it and close the question. My own script has this: `(cd /usr/local/bin && /usr/local/bin/MyCode)`

Comment: What's the actual message dialog text you're getting?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As you've discerned, the way to redirect the path on load is:

`(cd /usr/local/bin && /usr/local/bin/MyCode)`

Once we sort out how to correct the popup prompt, I'll add that in here as well.

Comment: To auto-run the script on clicking it, open nautilus, and under Preferences there's an item to specify executing text files. I found it from here: http://ubuntuforums.org/showthread.php?t=1934693