# How to run a Linux shell command from a different directory without getting there?

Tags: linux, bash, shell

How to run a Linux shell command from a different directory without actually getting there?

In the following, I want to run a `make` command, but without getting into the source code directory, i.e., from my home directory:

```
me@mypc:~$ ~/my/source/code/directory/make  #This is wrong!
```

I have seen some examples which suggest as:

```
me@mypc:~$ cd ~/my/source/code/directory; make
```

But this ends up taking me into that source code directory, which I want to avoid.

There could the be the other option:

```
me@mypc:~$ cd ~/my/source/code/directory; make; cd ~
```

But it becomes complicated in cese.

I am wondering if there could be some way nicer and simpler than these?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How do I run a program with a different working directory from current, from Linux shell?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/786376/how-do-i-run-a-program-with-a-different-working-directory-from-current-from-lin)

Comment: @Madivad, Thanks for pointing. Great to know that, [though can't do](http://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/265736/should-i-delete-my-question-if-it-is-marked-as-a-duplicate) nothing :|.

Comment: That's cool. I didn't want it gone,  just linked.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

You can try:

```
me@mypc:~$ (cd ~/my/source/code/directory; make)
```

Parentheses tell your shell to spawn a separate subshell, with its own current directory, and run the commands inside that subshell. After the command finishes, the subshell is closed, and you're back to your main shell, whose current directory never changed.

Answer (score 5):

Do it in a subshell, e.g.

```
(cd ~/my/source/code/directory; make)
```

Alternately, you can use make's `-C` option, e.g.

```
make -C ~/my/source/code/directory
```

Comment: Beware that `make -C` is non portable as `make` implementations are not required (by POSIX) to support it, on the other hand `(cd ...;make)` is definitely portable

Comment: Portability is more a concern for scripts, where the writer of the script is not necessarily the user of the script. For interactive use, it's a simple matter to use whatever technique is more convenient for whatever system you are on.

Answer (score 3):

You can also use

```
pushd ~/my/source/code/directory; make; popd
```

or

```
current=`pwd`; cd ~/my/source/code/directory; make; cd "$current"
```

Answer (score 0):

```
$ (cd directory && make)
```

You need to use `&&` instead of `;`. Consider something like

```
cd junk && rm -rf *
```

With `&&`, bash will abort if the directory `junk` does not exist. If you try `cd junk; rm -rf *` and `junk` doesn’t exist, you’ll delete everything in the current directory :(