# Run program in linux from different working directory involving input and output files

Tags: linux, shell, environment

My question is very similar to [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/786376/how-do-i-run-a-program-with-a-different-working-directory-from-current-from-lin) however I believe im not entirely sure how to do the following:

In a linux terminal I have a program located in `/a` called `run`. Normally I would run this program being inside `/a` and calling `./run input.case1` which will then read the contents of the file `input.case1` and save another file `output.case1` to the directory `/a`. To make matters worse, there are other files that the program reads when called, but that aren't explicitly passed in the way `input.case1` was. For instance the program will make use of `insettings.case1` and `outsettings.case1` which it assumes are in the directory from which we call the program, i.e. `/a`. This all works fine assuming I always work within directory.

However this is not ideal for me because I want to create input files using preprocessing scripts and process the resulting output files using  postprocessing scripts that are all located in a separate directory, lets call it `/b`. Is there a way to call `run` from `/b` with all the files that would normally have to be inside `/a` located in `/b` and having the output file saved to `/b` as well?

Answer (score 0):

You cold copy files from a to b.  Or do this by 
cd /a
. /run /b/inputfile
If you cant copy files