# multiple commands in cmake execute_process

Tags: git, cmake

I have a project that I am using cmake to help build.  The suppose the project is in `/home/proj` and the build directory is in `/home/proj-build`

The `/home/proj` directory is a git repository with some tags, and I would like to incorporate the most recent tag into the code when it gets built so that the binary knows what version it is.

In my `CMakeLists.txt` file I have the following stanza in the setup portion:

```
set(CMAKE_BUILD_TYPE None)
message(${CMAKE_CURRENT_SOURCE_DIR})
execute_process(COMMAND cd ${CMAKE_CURRENT_SOURCE_DIR} && exec git describe --abbrev=0 --always OUTPUT_VARIABLE GIT_VERSION)
message("${GIT_VERSION}")
set(CMAKE_C_FLAGS "${CMAKE_C_FLAGS} -D__GIT_VERSION=\\\"${GIT_VERSION}\\\"")
set(CMAKE_CXX_FLAGS "${CMAKE_CXX_FLAGS} -D__GIT_VERSION=\\\"${GIT_VERSION}\\\"")
```

The problem is that the compound command in the `execute_process` apparently returns an empty string for the version.  I have to somehow run the `git describe` command from inside the repository directory, but it is distinct from the build directory where the code is getting made.

How can I get the make process to execute the appropriate git command in the appropriate directory, even when envoked from the build directory?  Also, how can I get `cmake` to get the output from a compound command as I would normally expect in the shell?

**Things I've tried**

I've tried to surround the compound command with parentheses as suggested [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/786376/how-do-i-run-a-program-with-a-different-working-directory-from-current-from-lin%22here%22) in order to run the command in a sub-shell, but the output does not seem to be returned to the parent shell.

[This link](https://cmake.org/pipermail/cmake/2009-June/030158.html) suggests that `execute_process` can be run with several `COMMAND` invocations, but it seems the `stdout` from the first is piped to `stdin` of the next, so that won't produce the desired result.

I also tried explicitly envoking the shell using `sh -c` inside the `execute_process` structure.   I'm not sure I fully understood the results of this attempt but I could not get the `'` I would need in this situation to escape properly inside the `execute_process`.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Command `execute_process` has *WORKING_DIRECTORY* option, which intention is to set directory where *COMMAND* will be invoked:

```
execute_process(COMMAND  git describe --abbrev=0 --always 
    WORKING_DIRECTORY ${CMAKE_CURRENT_SOURCE_DIR}
    OUTPUT_VARIABLE GIT_VERSION
)
```

As for `&&` operand, it doesn't work with `execute_process`, because **shell isn't used** for run the command. This is explicitely stated in [documentation](https://cmake.org/cmake/help/v3.0/command/execute_process.html).

Normally, for achive *sequential* order of the commands, you need to call `execute_process` twice (or more). But such usage doesn't work with changing directory, that is why special option is introduced.