# While executing this code,I am getting an error ashorsepool.bash: line 10: ./horsepool: No such file or directory.What should I do now?

Tags: bash, shell, string-matching

```
#!/bin/sh
#BSUB -J shrutireddy_project
#BSUB -o Horsepool_output_world
#BSUB -e Horsepool_error
#BSUB -n 1
#BSUB -q ht-10g
#BSUB cwd /home/shrutireddy/
work=/home/shrutireddy/
cd $work
./horse world192.txt "string". --> error at this line.
```

What to do now to run the script successfully.
Thanks in advance.

Comment: Did you check to see if that script exists in the home dir?

Comment: see https://stackoverflow.com/questions/786376/how-do-i-run-a-program-with-a-different-working-directory-from-current-from-lin ... `(cd $work; ./horse world192.txt "string")` might work

Answer (score 0):

The error message does not come from the line you are indicating.

The message says that a file named *horsepool* is not found, but the indicated line does not contain any horsepool.

Since the reporting program, according to your posting, is *ashorsepool.bash*, I suggest that you examine this script. It should have an invocation of *horsepool* in line 10. You can also run it with `-x` to see exactly what is going on, for instance, if you do a cd on a shell variable, you can verify that the variable indeed contains the expected value.