# Allow sh to be run from anywhere

Tags: linux, sh

I have been monitoring the performance of my Linux server with ioping (had some performance degradation last year). For this purpose I created a simple script:

```
echo $(date) | tee -a ../sb-output.log | tee -a ../iotest.txt
./ioping -c 10 . 2>&1 | tee -a ../sb-output.log | grep "requests completed in\|ioping" | grep -v "ioping statistics" | sed "s/^/IOPing I\/O\: /" | tee -a ../iotest.txt
./ioping -RD . 2>&1 | tee -a ../sb-output.log | grep "requests completed in\|ioping" | grep -v "ioping statistics" | sed "s/^/IOPing seek rate\: /" | tee -a ../iotest.txt
etc
```

The script calls ioping in the folder /home/bench/ioping-0.6. Then it saves the output in readable form in /home/bench/iotest.txt. It also adds the date so I can compare points in time.

Unfortunately I am no experienced programmer and this version of the script only works if you first enter the right directory (/home/bench/ioping-0.6).

I would like to call this script from anywhere. For example by calling

```
sh /home/bench/ioping.sh
```

Googling this and reading about path variables was a bit over my head. I kept up ending up with different version of

> line 3: ./ioping: No such file or directory

Any thoughts on how to upgrade my scripts so that it works anywhere?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Getting the source directory of a Bash script from within](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/59895/getting-the-source-directory-of-a-bash-script-from-within)

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How do I run a program with a different working directory from current, from Linux shell?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/786376/how-do-i-run-a-program-with-a-different-working-directory-from-current-from-lin)

Comment: `echo $(date)` is a [useless use of `echo`](http://www.iki.fi/era/unix/award.html#echo) and I get the feeling the rest of your script could also be simplified significantly.

Answer (score 0):

Isn't it obvious? `ioping` is not in `.` so you can't use `./ioping`.

Easiest solution is to set `PATH` to include the directory where `ioping` is. perhaps more robust - figure out the path to `$0` and use that path as the location for `ioping` (assing your script sits next to `ioping`).

If iopinf itself depend on being ruin in a certain directory, you might have to make your script cd to the ioping directory before running.

Comment: Or rather, put `ioping` somewhere that already is in (or is commonly added to) one's path, such as `/usr/local/bin` or `~/bin`.

Answer (score 0):

The trick is the shell's `$0` variable. This is set to the path of the script.

```
#!/bin/sh

set -x
cd $(dirname $0)
pwd

cd ${0%/*}
pwd
```

If `dirname` isn't available for some reason, like some limited busybox distributions, you can try using shell parameter expansion tricks like the second one in my example.